# Visual Studio Mac Can't run ASP.NET Core Project

Tags: visual-studio-mac

This may be very obvious in hindsight. When installing the new VS Mac, and creating an ASPNET Core project, I can't run it by clicking the run button in the top left.

I can run if I right click on the Web project, click 'Run With' then 'Custom Configuration'. Works great.

However, the run item is disabled and I can't figure any way to enable it: http://prntscr.com/f7rsgh

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No - reached out to a bunch of people

Answer (score 1):

Try loading the solution using Jetbrains Rider. https://www.jetbrains.com/rider

Comment: With respect, I don't think this is an answer to the question. Nick G's answer below makes this relevant to Visual Studio for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it may be the same issue:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/79790/view.html

If you expand the comments, someone says:

> OK installing 2.1.0-preview1-006776 breaks VS Mac 7.0.1. I see the same problem that you are seeing. There is a NuGetFallbackFolder in the sdk folder and VSMac incorrectly uses that as the latest sdk folder. So for now you can fix this by removing the `/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/` folder. Although that may break the 2.1 preview version of the dotnet cli if you are using it from the command line. VSMac seems to be OK running and debugging ASP.NET Core projects after removing that folder.

It seems to have fixed the OP's question from the forum thread. This is a bug with Visual Studio for Mac that's been fixed in a pending release, but the update doesn't seem to be out just yet. I hope this helps you out in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

- Download and install the latest asp.net core
- Download or upgrade to
  the latest openSSL

This helped me